# Is sampling with respect on a infinite sample space equivalent to sampling without replacement? without

Tags: probability

$3$ numbers are drawn from sample space $Ω=\{1,2,...,N\}$ randomly with replacement . To find the probability that the third number falls between the first two if it is known that the first number is less than the second. The probability is $P=\frac{N-2}{3N}$. However,had the numbers been drawn without replacement this would have been $1/3$ irrespective of the value of $N$. Asymptotically, $P\to 1/3$ as $N\to ∞$. Now if we say $P^*$ is the probability of event when sampling is done without replacement and $P$ is the probability of event when sampling is done with replacement, can't we say in general that:
$$
\lim_{|Ω|\to∞} P = P^*
$$
Because whether we make a finite number of replacements from a sample space of infinite size or not there should be no difference between the result. Is this right?

Comment: I find what you have written difficult to follow.  But an infinite sample space in itself is not sufficient to give ties a $0$ probability: if for example $x\in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ has a probability $2^{-x}$ of being chosen then there is a positive probability of the same value being chosen more than once with replacement, while there is no "uniform distribution" on a countably infinite set such as  $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$